# Move store to alternative location on same server

Tags: magento-1, redirect, migration, server-setup

I want to move my store to a different location on the current server and keep it accessible for myself only. I will launch a new store at the same time.

The problem I have is that I cannot seem to access the store after creating a clone/duplicate (with new database), because it always redirects to the live store. (I don't want to take the live store down before I get the it to work as described above).

After duplicating the store to domains/www.mydomain.com/newlocation/ I have changed the domain in DB core_config_data and cleared all cache and sessions in \var. Still it keeps redirecting. Would make sense if the .htaccess would have something to do with it, but even after completely making it empty it still redirects. I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What to do after duplicating a Magento instance:

- change the database credentials in `app/etc/local.xml`
- change the base urls in the `core_config_data` table
- clear Magento cache
- clear browser cache in case it has already cached a redirect
- change `.htaccess` (or vhost server configuration) if it contains additional redirects or store selection based on the URL

Comment: All done, but about the .htaccess, can you explain a bit more about this? I can post the contents of the file if needed.

Comment: In short: if you find the old base url somewhere in the .htaccess file, you need to change it. But you can post the file if you are unsure

Comment: It's to big to post here, but you can download it here [link](http://majamagazines.nl/htaccess.zip). Just change .zip to .txt. The url location I want to move to is www.popularmagazines.co.uk/oud/

Comment: The file is fine, nothing to do there.

Comment: Must be some local server config then.... Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Finally did it. You have to do all the steps like described above, but I  in core_config_data also set "web/url/redirect_to_base" to 0. This did the job.